# Javascript: Merge two JSONs based on other fields

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 json inputs like this:

```
[
  {
    userId: 32159,
    userFirstName: "john",
    userLastName: "doe",
    plans: [ ]
  },
  {
    userId: 32157,
    userFirstName: "dave",
    userLastName: "mess",
    plans: [ ]
  }
]
```

and

```
[
      {
        userId: 32159,
        userFirstName: "john",
        userLastName: "doe",
        results: [ ]
      },
      {
        userId: 32157,
        userFirstName: "dave",
        userLastName: "mess",
        results: [ ]
      }
]
```

and I want the output as :

```
[
      {
        userId: 32159,
        userFirstName: "john",
        userLastName: "doe",
        plans: [ ],
        results: [ ]
      },
      {
        userId: 32157,
        userFirstName: "dave",
        userLastName: "mess",
        plans: [ ],
        results: [ ]
      }
 ]
```

How to do it in javascript.Please help.Here userId is a unique field

Comment: You just want to simply add 2 set?

Comment: Can we assume that the arrays are the same size? And ppl are sorted in those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) each object, this can be achieved by looping through one of the collections, and then selecting the corresponding object and extending it, like so...

```
var collectionA = [], collectionB = [],
    result = [];

$.each(collectionA, function(i, objA) {
    $.each(collectionB, function(j, objB) {
        if (objA.userId === objB.userId) {
            result.push($.extend({}, objA, objB);
            return false;
        }
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's extend function:

```
var json1 = [{
    userId: 32159,
    userFirstName: "john",
    userLastName: "doe",
    plans: []
}, {
    userId: 32157,
    userFirstName: "dave",
    userLastName: "mess",
    plans: []
}];

var json2 = [{
    userId: 32157,
    userFirstName: "dave",
    userLastName: "mess",
    results: []
}, {
    userId: 32159,
    userFirstName: "john",
    userLastName: "doe",
    results: []
}];

var jsonCombined = [];

for (i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < json2.length; i2++) {
        if (json1[i].userId == json2[i2].userId) 
            jsonCombined.push($.extend(json1[i], json2[i2]));
    }
}

console.log(jsonCombined);
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/9qDdv/)

Answer (score 0):

you can user underscore-min.js file and try as below by using its inbuild function

```
 _.each(json1, function(val1) {
    _.each(json2, function(val2) {
            if (val1.userId = val2.userId) {
                _.extend(val1, val2.results);
            }
        }

    })

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure JavaScript. One solution might look like this.

```
function copy(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var x in obj1)
        if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(x))
            obj2[x] = obj1[x];
}

function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    var fin = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        fin.push({});
        copy(arr1[i], fin[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
        copy(arr2[i], fin[i]);

    return fin;
}

merge(yourfirstobject, yoursecondobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is called Simultaneous Processing in Functional Programming. 
You have two pieces of data, and you want to process them together to get a result. Consider this code

http://repl.it/Ll1/1

```
// Array Array -> Array
// Assume that length of a is equal to length of b
// and items sorted in the right way to match records
function zip(a,b) {
    // Object Object -> Object
    function add_results(item_a,item_b) {
        item_a["results"] = item_b["results"]
        return item_a;
    }
    if(a.length===0) {
        return [];
    } else {
        return [add_results(a[0],b[0])].concat(zip(a.slice(1),b.slice(1)));
    }
}

zip(a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd divide up the work into discrete functions:

```
function mergeObjects(a, b) {
  if (a && b) { for (var key in b) { a[key] = b[key]; } }
  return a;
}

function mergeAndSortArrays(a, b) {
    return a
        .concat(b)
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a.userId - b.userId; });
}

function combine(a, b) {
    var a = mergeAndSortArrays(a, b);
    for (var i = 0, l = a.length - 1; i < l; i++) {
        if (a[i].userId === a[i+1].userId) {
            a[i] = mergeObjects(a[i], a[i+1]);
            a.splice(i+1, 1);
            i--; l--;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

combine(a, b);
```